# Menu css3 & jquery with blur effect

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I have a problem with my menu on website: http://goo.gl/xc1E5F

When you hover the mouse over the button "About", other buttons have effect blur permanently.
I would like to make this blur disappear after one second (that was without).
(exaclty like when you use automatic focus with a camera, It adjust the focus and then goes away)

Can somebody help me?
THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

[css3](/questions/tagged/css3)  [animation](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) should be your  solution:

```
@keyframes myfirst{
    0%   {
        background: transparent;
        color: #000;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    }
    50%  {
        background:  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
        color: transparent;
        text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000;
    }
    100% {
        background: transparent;
        color: #000;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    }
}
```

I've created a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7JDuh/1/)** to demonstrate it.

Comment: It does not work that good :( because as you move the mouse over the buttons horizontally this blur is only one text. Check for example and move the mouse from "About" to "Works".

Comment: since the blur is triggered on hover of `.main-navigation`, when you hover from one `li` to another without moving away from `.main-navigation`, the blur animation doesn't fire again. However, the `li` you just hovered away from gets its `a:hover` styles removed, and reverts to the `.main-navigation:hover li a` styles, and gets blurred.

Comment: Dpeif, can you make example for me in fiddle like Barnee? Thanks!